# Backbone.js: PATCH url endpoint wrong

Tags: backbone.js

I have a model like this:

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'backbone'
], function ($) {
    var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({


        url: 'articles/',

        initialize: function(){

        }

    });

    return MyModel;
});
```

And this is the code for saving the object:

```
        article = new Article();

        status = t.currentTarget.textContent;
        article.set('ready', {'status': status});

        coords = this.model.get('location').coords;
        article.set('geo', {'lat': coords.latitude, 'lng': coords.longitude});

        article.save(null, { accessToken: true }).done(function(){
            self.hideIcons();
        });
```

But when I do the PATCH:

```
this.article.save({comment: comment}, {patch: true, accessToken: true});
```

The request is correctly PATCH, but the endpoint is wrong, the request is like this:

```
PATCH mydomain.com/articles/
```

As you can see, should be:

```
PATCH mydomain.com/articles/<last-model-id-created>/
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting the `Model.url` property, you should set `Model.urlRoot`. From the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot):

> Specify a urlRoot if you're using a model outside of a collection, to enable the default url function to generate URLs based on the model id. "[urlRoot]/id"

If the model belongs to a collection, you can leave `Model.urlRoot` unspecified as well and set `Collection.url` instead.